# call to custom create_user via form fails

Tags: python, django

I have a form that I am going to be using for user registration and want to use the same create_user function that is defined in my custom user manager, however, when the user data is submitted, the values are going into the database in a way that is not corresponding with what was entered and instead each time, the user email_address is entered as "abstractuser.MyUser.object" instead of what was given to the form.  How can I modify this code to pass the correct value to the create_user function and create the user successfully?
Thanks.

**Models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin

# Create your models here.
class MyManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, email_address, password):
        superuser = MyUser()
        superuser.email_address = email_address
        superuser.set_password(password)
        superuser.is_staff = True
        superuser.is_superuser = True
        superuser.save()

    def create_user(self, email_address, password):
        user = MyUser()
        user.email_address = email_address
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = False
        user.save()
        return user

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email_address = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=0)

    object = MyManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email_address'

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email_address
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from models import MyUser

class AuthForm(ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['email_address', 'password']
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from forms import AuthForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# Create your views here.
def user_create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        get_user_model().object.create_user(self, request.POST)

    return render(request, 'abstractuser/user_create.html', {'form': AuthForm})
```

**EDIT**

Thank you all for the input, I have added the self parameter to the create_user function and added self parameter to the call to create_user, however, now I get the error, '**global name 'self' is not defined**'.  What is the proper way to get self in this scenario?

**TRACEBACK**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/user/create

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['abstractuser',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/dev/DjangoProjects/abstracttest/abstractuser/views.py" in user_create
  8.         get_user_model().object.create_user(self, request.POST)

Exception Type: NameError at /user/create
Exception Value: global name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: you can following [this source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L151-L154), and don't miss about `self` parameter.

Comment: @SancaKembang Thank you I have added that but still have issues.  Please see edit.

Comment: and also `return user`, don't used it inside your views...But only, `def create_user(self, email_address, password):`

Comment: added return statement to end of create_user function and posted traceback

Comment: change your `get_user_model().object.create_user(self, request.POST)` to `get_user_model().object.create_user(request.POST)`...

Comment: I have tried that and get an error stating that create_user takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: If you read [this docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUserManager.create_user), has 3 minimum arguments... http://pastebin.com/GwNWYzQe, don't miss to `return superuser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Sanca for your input, however, this has been resolved with the following additions to the views.py user_create function

```
get_user_model().object.create_user(request.POST['email_address'],request.POST['password'])
```

and models.py MyManager.create_user looks like this:

```
def create_user(self, email_address, password):
    user = MyUser()
    user.email_address = email_address
    user.set_password(password)
    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_superuser = False
    user.save()
    return user
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy my code. Nothing difference by a glance.

models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using = self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
    user = self.create_user(email, password)
    user.is_admin=True
    user.is_staff=True
    user.is_superuser=True
    user.save(using = self._db)
    return user

class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email               = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', unique=True, max_length=60)
    date_joined         = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login          = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active           = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff            = models.BooleanField(default=False) 

    USERNAME_FIELD      = 'email'
    # REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username',]
    objects             = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj = None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_lebel):
        return True
```

And then you can call create_user from views with user instance.